# Implement Android Tabs without actionBar.newTab()

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am new to Android Development, and I am implementing some basic programs.
My minimum SDK is KitKat.

I want to create an App which has multiple tabs.
I am using the following approach:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");
```

But these methods are deprecated in Android Studio now.

How do I get the exact implementation of this code according to new methods?

PLEASE EXPLAIN IN DETAIL.

www.developer.android.com is very complicated for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want android tabs that look like the ones in Googles Updated apps like the Play store then you would have to use ViewPager and two java files from Googles open source I/O 2014 app.

If you are a beginner, I recommend not using android developer website for common things like android tabs because they just make it too much over complicated and its almost like Computer science degree, you only use 40% of what you learn. There is hundreds of tutorials websites and blogs out there that will show you how to do the same thing but in a much more digestible way :D

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Extremely useful info.. Do you also have a tutorial to implement the Navigation Drawer along with the tabs? Please send me a link if you have one ... ! @edwinj

Comment: Your Welcome! I havent made a tutorial on it but this is a pretty good tutorial on developing material design navigation drawer: http://d-codepages.com/index.php/android/android-advanced/26-material-design-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 1):

> Prior to Android "L" preview, the easiest way to setup tabs with
>   Fragments was to use ActionBar Tabs as described in ActionBar Tabs
>   with Fragments guide. However, all methods related to navigation modes
>   in the ActionBar class (such as setNavigationMode(), addTab(),
>   selectTab(), etc.) are now deprecated.
>
> As a result, tabs are now best implemented by leveraging the ViewPager
>   with a custom "tab indicator" on top. In this guide, we will be
>   implementing the custom tab indicator using the Google recommended
>   method : **SlidingTabs Layout**

Check out [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout) codepath tutorial if you want to learn in more detail how to implement it.

There is an easier approach using a third-party library : [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I think the best thing to use is PagerSlidingTabStrip.  You can test it out by choosing the Android Studio Tabbed Activity preset when creating your project (instead of Blank Activity, Fragment etc.) and see how you like it.  Here's a tutorial on how to use it:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpagertabstrip-fragments-tutorial/

Keep in mind that your going to have to add the pagertabstrip inside of the `activity_main.xml` if you choose the Android Studio preset. Like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

If you have anymore questions, just ask.